# How best to store roast coffee beans?

Tags: storage-method, coffee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good ways to store coffee?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1188/good-ways-to-store-coffee)

I opened a new bag of roasted coffee beans yesterday and put them in a plastic box - a box with a good seal, with clip-down sides. And I put the box in the cupboard.

Is there a better way to keep the beans? It'll take probably a few weeks for me to get thru the beans.

I heard that the cool of the refrigerator is good, but that the beans can get damp in the fridge. I heard the freezer is good, but I thought the same could happen…

How about this:

I was thinking of bagging the beans in portions of the amount I'll use each day. Putting the bags in the plastic box, and putting that in the freezer. Then each day I'd take out a portion of beans to defrost ready to grind the next day. I would use cheap bags, not freezer bags. The idea is that the bags might help because the beans wouldn't be exposed to air and possible moisture each time I open the box.