# Is it necessary to store purchased sealed Coffee powder in freezer? Why?

Tags: storage-method, coffee, freezing

I purchased few packets of 100 gms freshly ground and roasted Coffee powder.
These packets do NOT have air filled in them like the chips packets.

Is it necessary to store purchased ***sealed*** roasted Coffee powder in freezer? Why?

Comment: see also http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/43788/if-you-need-to-keep-ground-coffee-for-a-long-time-will-keeping-it-in-the-freeze?rq=1

Comment: @rumtscho That question deals with "home" ground coffee - that's why they are talking about keeping it in containors. My coffe is already sealed. should I open it and then keep in in airtight containors? Also since my cofee is already sealed will it still absord moisture from air?

Comment: I didn't read the other question that way (he only says that he cannot home-grind the beans directly before drinking, but doesn't specify who grinds the coffee he stores). But OK, maybe there is a difference indeed. Reopening.

Answer (score 4):

**It is NOT necessary to store coffee in the freezer.**

It can be helpful if you want to store it for long periods - i.e. months.

Ground coffee should NOT be thawed and re-frozen, nor opened frequently and put-back in the freezer. Think of your freezer as long-term storage, and take out a week's worth of coffee at a time.

Also, it's not going to make a huge difference either way - if you want better tasting coffee the best bang-for-buck would be buying whole-bean coffee and grinding it as you need it.

Here's an obsessively detailed taste-testing account:

http://www.home-barista.com/store-coffee-in-freezer-conclusions.html